# Реализовать итерационную функцию на python

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import math


def main(n, m, a):
    f = 0
    for i in range(1, a + 1):
        for k in range(1, m + 1):
            for j in range(1, n + 1):
                f += (94 * k ** 5 - 67 * math.log10(j) ** 6 - 83 * i ** 4)
    f = "{:.2e}".format(f)
    print(f)
    return f
main(8, 3, 5)
```

Не работает код, вместо `-1.11e+06` выдает `-9.14e+05`
А при 7, 7, 6 верно выдает `1.05e+08`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что в качестве функции натурального логарифма нужно использовать `math.log`, а не `math.log10`. Тогда будет правильный ответ.

*Немного отрефакторил код:*

```py
from math import log

def f(n: int, m: int, a: int):
    result = 0
    for i in range(1, a+1):
        for k in range(1, m+1):
            for j in range(1, n+1):
                result += (94 * k**5 - 67 * log(j)**6 - 83 * i**4)

    return f'{result:.2e}'
```

Проверка:

```py
print(f(8, 3, 5))
```

Вывод:

```py
-1.11e+06
```

Проверка 2:

```py
print(f(7, 7, 6))
```

Вывод:

```py
1.05e+08
```

Comment: Спасибо большое